# Cannot destructure property 'uid' of 'object null' as it is null

Tags: angular, pipe, observable, switchmap

So I had a function in Angular named appUser$, the error said "Cannot destructure property 'uid' of 'object null' as it is null."

```
  get appUser$(): Observable<AppUser> {
    return this.user$.pipe(
      switchMap(({uid})=> this.userService.get(uid)));
  }
```

Then I changed it to:

```
  get appUser$(): Observable<AppUser> {
    return this.user$.pipe(
      switchMap(({uid})=> {
        if({uid}){
          return this.userService.get(uid);
        } else {
          return of(null);
        }
      }));   
  }
```

But still it doesnt work, any ideas?

Comment: perhaps using `if (uid != undefined) { .. }`, then it would check both null and undfined conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, but I think you have an issue with the function argument:
I mean the argument is null and you are trying to get the uid from null.

try like this:

```
 get appUser$(): Observable<AppUser> {
    return this.user$.pipe(
      switchMap((obj)=> {
        if(obj && obj.uid){
          return this.userService.get(obj.uid);
        } else {
          return of(null);
        }
      }));   
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there any specific reason why the argument is enclosed as an object? The de-structuring issue is stemming from this assignment. You could try to use it directly

```js
get appUser$(): Observable<AppUser> {
  return this.user$.pipe(
    switchMap(uid => this.userService.get(uid))
  );
}
```